# Recieve datatable from code behind to Javascript two demintion array?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, datatable

I have an application based on google map, in which I need to use a javascript matrix (2d array) for the map's parameters.

I have a datatable with the information at my code behind file:

```
..query code, getting value from the db..
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
```

How do I pass this datatable values into a js two denominational array?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Oded, implementing a js dataset using JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is on the aspx page to have where appropriate

```
<script type="text/javascript>
    var mapData = <%=mapData%>
</script>
```

Then in your code behind create a public string called mapData and assign it as a json string.
e.g.

```
mapData = "{({name:'blah',lat:10.223,long:57.899},{etc})};
```

- obviously loop through your dataset to create the string.

You can then use it in your javascript on the page

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax for retrieve the data table as an array from the server.

```
public ArrayList ConvertDT(ref DataTable dt)
{
   ArrayList converted = new ArrayList(dt.Rows.Count);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            converted.Add(row);
    return converted;
    }
```

then array list convert into array and send back as a response to the client

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/91826-datatable-to-array/

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Jquery Ajax? With Jquery Ajax you can bring data from server side to client side.